# Can't ask question so what next?

Tags: discussion, support

Previously I asked what to do after being blocked from asking question.

It looked like they are full of rhetoric on asking good questions but nothing on how to proceed after some questions are deemed "bad" and a block is set up.

Previously I asked if I can edit the "bad" questions ( assuming negative votes means bad) to ask good questions, here is an example of what wouldn't work:

[Can I copy a project from CodePlex to GitHub](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351836/can-i-copy-a-project-from-codeplex-to-github)

Asking the question got negative votes, but the answer to the question has got more positive votes! So bad questions can leads to good answers!

Now I am stuck with above, can't delete it because of the good answer, and cant edit it as it makes the answer irrelevant to the question.

Of course manual intervention is out of question, since that is all is provided with asking bad questions.

My question is what next? What to do once being blocked by a feature that was is obviously a manager's brain spark with no afterthought of how to proceed after block.

I tried deleting, editing "bad" questions , but looks like being in a block is just how things are.

I ask again : My question is what next? what the user is suppose to do after getting deadlocked, just sit and wait indefinitely till when the block might be lifted? can't improve/remove previous "bad" questions to try again? There are "good" answers to "bad" questions, but the question remains "bad"?

Comment: system allows blocked users to ask one question in 6 months (and depending on how well is this question received ban may be lifted). Another option is to delete one's account then recreate it, in this case system allows one to start asking at a rate of one question a week

Comment: A relevant quote from the answer linked by Gnat: *“if you're blocked from new questions, contributing good answers is one method to work toward having the block listed.”* You have posted two answers nine years ago, and none since then; maybe you can find some unanswered questions related to the subjects you know well, and start increasing your reputation by answering them.