# We are no longer accepting questions from this account?

Tags: discussion

Can anyone shed a light on this ? My last question received two answers, no criticism and it was as comprehensive as possible.

One closed vote without citing a reason.
One upvote and a downvote without citing any reason

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/why-am-i-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)

Comment: you can check deleted questions by this URL: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current Also, you have asked about this [about half year ago](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9154/31260)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't ask question so what next?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/cant-ask-question-so-what-next)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your profile now, there doesn't appear to be an active block. However, you were blocked about 9 hours ago (as of the time of writing this).

It appears that you are on the cusp of the automated blocking system. Looking at all of your questions, I see a total of 13 questions. The net score of all of these questions is 1. The net score of undeleted questions is 9. 7 questions are deleted. It's not fully known what goes into the automated block algorithm, but deleted questions (self-deleted, community-deleted, and moderator-deleted all count), question score, and overall net score are commonly believed to be input.

Unfortunately, not only are the details of the system not publicly known, but people are free to vote (up, down, close, or reopen) as they see fit and aren't any obligation to provide feedback.

I recommend reading [this question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3041/4) (or [its Meta Stack Exchange counterpart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/572)) to understand more about the automated block system

Comment: Thank you , I think pretty much my last question was really my final question anyway , it is an irony that a systems engineering forum is turned into a black box. From the comment and answer to my last question I think I am probably good for the test of my life without asking anymore system engineering questions. Hopefully all the answers I'll ever need have already been asked .